# How to Bind a DropDownList to a FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, formview

I'm trying to bind a `DropDownlist` with some **Categories** in a `FormView` to insert **Products**

I'm Using `ItemType="Product"` in the `FormView`.

The `Textboxes` are binded this way for the product description: `Text="<%# BindItem.Name%>"`

But I can't seem to bind the `DropDownList`. I have seen solutions using the **SelectedValue** attribute **but that doesn't even shows up as an attribute** for my `DropDownList` in the aspx page.

In my code behind there is the `InsertMethod` for the `FormView`:

```
Product item = new Product();

TryUpdateModel(item);

if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     ProductsBLL prod = new ProductsBLL();
     prod.Insert(item);
  }
```

The aspx page is a standard webform:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Marcar Férias</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppModal" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:FormView runat="server" CssClass="table" ID="frmViewProdutos" DefaultMode="Insert" ItemType="NovoGRH.ENTIDADES.Produtos" DataKeyNames="Id" InsertMethod="frmViewProdutos_InsertItem">
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="ddlExercicio" runat="server">Categoria: </asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategoria" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Descricao" SelectMethod="CarregarCategorias">
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txtNomeProduto" runat="server">Nome: </asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNomeProduto" CssClass="form-control" Text="<%# BindItem.NomeProduto%>" runat="server" Width="80" ></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSalvarCrud" Text="Salvar" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                            </div>
                            <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="validaForm" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowSummary="true" />

                        </InsertItemTemplate>

                    </asp:FormView>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working OK. Except that I can't make it work for the **CategoryID** stored in the DropDownList

Comment: Can you show your view ?

Comment: I added the aspx page in the question now :)